# Pi Zero W unable to connect to Wifi

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w

I got myself a Pi Zero W a few weeks back. After installing Raspbian on a sdcard and doing all the setup procedures (making the wpa_supplicant.conf file), I was able to connect it to my wifi. Then just a few days back, due to reasons, I had to re-install Raspbian on my SD card. After following the same procedures for setup for wifi connection, my Pi Zero hasn't been able to connect to my wifi. The wpa_supplicant.conf file contains this

```
network={  
        ssid="wifi1"  
        psk="password1"  
        key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK  
}  

network={  
        ssid="wifi2"  
        psk="password2"  
        key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK  
}
```

Please, can anyone tell me a solution or if I am missing out any steps?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd` ?  And does `sudo ifconfig` show the WiFi interface?

Comment: If this is the total content of the file, it is missing the header. What you have listed is intended to be APPENDED to the file. I believe Stretch is more strict than Jessie.

Comment: Another thing to look for these days is that the Pi Zero W requires 2.4Ghz wifi.

Answer (score 1):

My problems with the pi0w were seen in `systemctl status dhcpcd` which stated, that there were problems starting up. So I fixed my `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file contains:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AT

network={
        ssid="network_name
        psk="pw"
}
```

Since you do not want to write your password in clear text, you can issue

```
wpa_passphrase ssid pw
```

and the the resulting string for the network entry. This is a hashed password. But remember to delete the commented clear password.
I hope this helps! Otherwise provide more data from your systemctl output.

Answer (score 0):

The later versions of Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS disable/block the WiFi by default (with `rfkill`) untill the country code is set using the `raspi-config` utility (select 5. Localisation Options-> WLAN Country). This does two things - it sets the country code (e.g. `country=GB` for UK) in the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file and crucially it unblocks the WiFi interface using the `rfkill` system. The rfkill utility can be run directly to unblock the wifi:

```
 sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

The above all applies if you can actually log into the Pi Zero - if not then if you mount the sdcard as a drive on another computer - it should appear as the `boot` drive. Then you can copy a suitable `wpa_supplicant.conf` file (see @mike's answer as an example) to the boot directory. It *should* then work... But if not then you may need to the edit the `cmdline.txt` file in the `boot` directory and add these two parameters on the end of the first line:

```
systemd.restore_state=0 rfkill.default_state=1
```

The first one disables the systemd rfkill restore service, whilst the second sets the default kernel rfkill status to enabled.